# Convert cell string with commas and spaces to vector

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I tried to convert the cell *x*:

```
x(1,:) = {'35,35, ,35'}; 
x(2,:) = {'40,40,30,40'};
x(3,:) = {'10, , ,'};
```

to a matrix with:

```
R = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,x,'un',0));
```

but the outcome omits the first row:

```
 R =

    40    40    30    40
```

but I was expecting:

```
 R =

    35    35     0    35
    40    40    30    40
    10     0     0     0
```

How can this be done?
thanks!

Comment: Does it works when you use   `x = {35,35, 0,35; 40,40,30,40};`? Notice the 0 in the empty position

Comment: It does work, but I can't insert 0's

Comment: @LuisMendo
x(1,:) = {'35,35, ,35'};
x(2,:) = {'40,40,30,40'};
cell2mat errors: Error using cat, Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: So you want `str2num` to interpret the missing number as a `0`. Based on your example, simply replacing spaces by the character `'0'` would work. But whether that's acceptable or not depends on your data format (you have only given an example)

Comment: unfortunately x also has cases like x(3,:) that I added above

Comment: So, replace `','` by `',0'`? `R = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num,strrep(x, ',', ',0'),'un',0));`

Comment: That worked! Thanks @LuisMendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Split](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) `x` by `,`, convert to double using [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) and [fill the missing values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html) with `0` as follows:

```
R = fillmissing(str2double(split(x,',')),'constant',0);
```

```
>> R
R =
   35   35    0   35
   40   40   30   40
   10    0    0    0
```

<sup>**Note:** Avoid using [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) since it is implemented using [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html). Read the security considerations and unintended side effects of using that in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) for details.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually. Please try this script to achieve what you are searching for

```
clear
clc
x(1,:) = {'35,35, ,35'}; 
x(2,:) = {'40,40,30,40'};

for i = 1: length(x)
   v1 = split(x(i),",");
   for j = 1:length(v1)
       if length(str2num(v1{j})  )==0
            oo(j)=0;
       else
      oo(j)= str2num(v1{j});
       end
   end
    R(i,:) = oo(1,:);
end
```